# In MQTT PUBLICATION

Tags: contiki

In contiki os, during mqtt publication, this error message is showed : "Client: *** ongoing Publication already, not queued!. how to remove this printed message from the publication of sensor data.

I want to change any macro regarding these in mqtt.h or mqtt.c ?
what is actual problem and give the solution.

regards,
kamalesh